# How can I identify the cause of an E4 plugin not starting

Tags: debugging, e4

I have created a simplemost E4 plugin based on the example templates in Eclipse. I have made no changes. When starting a new Eclipse instance depending only on the plugins transitive dependencies, the menu appears correctly. When I try to install it into my running instance, the model spy shows that the fragment has not merged. The command is missing. There are no error messages pertaining to E4 as far as I can see.

How would I debug such a situation? I have not found any information on this, and most tutorials seem to assume that I want to build a complete application. However, I merely want to provide a contribution to on an existing E4 application.

Comment: Install it how? You can't just copy things to the plugins directory. Does the existing app actually support additions?

Comment: @greg-449 I am aware of that, although the drop-ins directory would provide such an installation style as well. In my case, the application is an e4 application with the legacyIDE application model. I perform the installation with the [Export and Install into the Running Host](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/ui_export_install_into_host.htm?cp=4_2_4_0) feature. Under the wrappers it creates a feature or feature patch for the plugin and then installs it using P2 installation. Will this information help you to answer my question?